# Why angular factory not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is simple angular factory which almost works. I want to reset my model and I tried  to add a method called '`resetModel`' but it doesn't work as It is not resetting the model properties. Could someone please explain why?

```
app.factory('programLocationModel', [ "$rootScope", function ($rootScope)
{

    var ProgramLocationModel = function()
    {
        this.name            =  "All Programmes";
        this.description     =  "";
        this.category        =  "";
        this.series          =  {};
        this.channel         =  {};
        this.duration        =  "";
        this.airTime         =  "";
        this.seriesName      =  "";
        this.url             =  "../assets/images/nhkw_thumbnail.jpg"; //Default client logo

    }

    ProgramLocationModel.prototype.update           = function( data )
    {

        this.name            =  data.name;
        this.description     =  data.description;
        this.category        =  data.category;
        this.series          =  data.series;
        this.seriesName      =  data.seriesName;
        this.channel         =  data.channel;
        this.duration        =  data.duration;
        this.airTime         =  data.airTime;
        this.url             =  $rootScope.resturl + '/graph/' + data.id + '/thumbnail?access_token=' + $rootScope.token;
    }


    ProgramLocationModel.prototype.resetModel = function () {

        ProgramLocationModel();
    }

    return new ProgramLocationModel();

} ] );
```

Comment: that's not how javascript works

Comment: @user1737909 obviously. But i guess it would be helpful if you would explain how it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resetModel function is only calling the constructor and not doing anything to the actual instance the method is called on. Your resetModel function is supposed to modify the properties of *this*, just like you already do in the constructor and in your update method.
Here is a simple way to do it:

```
app.factory('programLocationModel', [ "$rootScope", function ($rootScope)
{

    var ProgramLocationModel = function()
    {
       this.resetModel();
    }

    ProgramLocationModel.prototype.update           = function( data )
    {

        this.name            =  data.name;
        this.description     =  data.description;
        this.category        =  data.category;
        this.series          =  data.series;
        this.seriesName      =  _seriesName;
        this.channel         =  data.channel;
        this.duration        =  data.duration;
        this.airTime         =  data.airTime;
        this.url             =  $rootScope.resturl + '/graph/' + data.id + '/thumbnail?access_token=' + $rootScope.token;
    }


    ProgramLocationModel.prototype.resetModel = function () {
        this.name            =  "All Programmes";
        this.description     =  "";
        this.category        =  "";
        this.series          =  {};
        this.channel         =  {};
        this.duration        =  "";
        this.airTime         =  "";
        this.seriesName      =  "";
        this.url             =  "../assets/images/nhkw_thumbnail.jpg"; //Default client logo
    }

    return new ProgramLocationModel();

} ] );
```